# Regex that works in JS not working in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex

This regexp:

```
/^admin$|^[А-Яа-я]{2,20}\s[А-Яа-я]{2,20}\s[А-Яа-я]{2,20}$/
```

should match this string:

```
Пупкин Василий Иванович
```

It does match in JS (tested in Firebug console) and doesn't in PHP, and I cannot understand why.

Comment: Did you escape the backslashes?

Comment: Hmm it does seem to work. See [this](http://regex101.com/r/mT0wD0)

Comment: @Biffen, now I tried with backslashes escaped, the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, strings are always UTF-8. In PHP, however, they are a sequence of bytes. In order to allow PHP's regex engine to handle UTF-8 strings, add the `u` modifier to the regex.

You can also simplify your regex by removing all the uppercase letter ranges and using the `i` modifier, however this may be locale-dependent so be sure to test it!

For more on modifiers, check the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)!

Comment: In layman's terms: Add an `u` to the end of your regex in PHP. Add an `ui` for unicode *and* case-insensitiveness.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use:

```
\p{Cyrillic}
```

Read [Unicode character properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) for more information.